# Disable revert chunk in codemirror merge view

Tags: javascript, merge, codemirror

I am trying to play with the [demo](http://codemirror.net/demo/merge.html) of codemirror merge view and I wanted to disable the Revert Chunk link. Can anyone tell me if this is doable or if there is an option to turn off ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can style the `CodeMirror-merge-copy` class to have `display: none`, that'd simply hide the buttons and thus provide no way to access that feature.

Answer (score 4):

It seems there is a new option for this according to the [official documentation](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#addon_merge):  simply set the `revertButtons` option to `false`.